# run-time error 3075 syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, runtime-error, mismatch

I have been struggling with this NUMBER(listed in Table) syntax this morning - I have a form with a combo box [cboIndicator] that looks up the value [Severity Indicator] from a table called tbl_ASPACSplitInventorySelect. Right now Severity Indicators 1-5 are correct, but the NULL value in the combobox box are spitting out an 3075 error.

```
Private Sub cboIndicator_AfterUpdate()
Dim myIndicator As String
myIndicator = "Select * from tbl_ASPACSplitInventorySelect where ([Severity Indicator] = '" & Me.cboIndicator
Me.ASPACSplitInventorySelect_subform1.Form.RecordSource = myIndicator
Me.ASPACSplitInventorySelect_subform1.Requery
Me.cboGrouping = Null
Me.Combo830 = Null
End Sub
```

I'm receiving a run-time error 3075 syntax error. As you can tell there is a subform listed and double checked all source objects. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Line Four appears to be the highlighted for data mismatch.

Comment: Can you tag this with the appropriate programming language?  Think about it...how could anyone answer this without that information?

Comment: Thank roryap, didn't even notice the sql tag was missing

Comment: It's not sql.  It looks more like VB.  But you can't assume that people know that.  And what flavor of vb?  VB.NET?  VBA?

Comment: Also, you need to tell us more information: for example, what line is the error occurring on?

Comment: In the where clause, are you comparing two same data types?

Comment: Thanks roryap, but the database runs both access-vba and sql together. I'm receiving this error on line four after I run a combo box entry to find all records that have a priority 1 status. The combo box has priority indicators 1-5 and pull data within table ASPACAplitInventory.

Comment: Thanks sagi, but why would I compare two data types.. I think the issue lies somewhere in ([Severity Indicator] = '" & Me.cboIndicator & "')".  It's set up as a string and I don't think the '" or '")" is correct for numerical data types.

Comment: `"Select * from tbl_ASPACSplitInventorySelect where [Severity Indicator] = " & Me.cboIndicator`

Comment: Thank You HansUp! I recognize your name from many posts before. I used the same code posted in the original post for GroupingNumber afterupdate and it worked, but was listed for a text value. Why is the  & "')" working text versus number?

Comment: So Now I'm receiving Run-Time error '3075' when I select the blank in NULL value in the drop-down. Values 1-5 are working filter values right now. Query Expression '[Severity Indicator] ='

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @K.D.  Please revise the question to include the code you're using now ... which gives you error #3075 ... and indicate which line of that code triggers the error.

Comment: @HansUp ... Just revised the question to include the new code. Line four is triggered.

Comment: Thanks!  That is not the query I thought you were using now.  I suggested `= " & Me.cboIndicator` and you have `= '" & Me.cboIndicator` instead.  Add a new line after `myIndicator = "Select * ...` and put this in that new line: `Debug.Print myIndicator`  Then run the code and examine the statement text in the Immediate window.  (Ctrl+g will take you there.)

Comment: @HansUp You are indeed correct with = " & Me.cboIndicator and I placed the Debug.Print myIndicator with nothing return before or after I select the NULL in the combobox.

Comment: So when the combobox is Null, doesn't the Immediate window show you this as the last part of the statement?  `where [Severity Indicator] =`  (with nothing after the `=` sign?)  What records should be selected when the combobox is Null?

Comment: Correct Nothing after the equals sign. There a blanks within thew column data that should be listed after the NULL value is selected. I learned at little trick consolidate the list of 39,000 record values into NULL, 1-5 by selecting crosstab function within the select query associated with the combobox. @HansUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the statement

```
myIndicator = "Select * from tbl_ASPACSplitInventorySelect where ([Severity Indicator] = '" & Me.cboIndicator
```

a quote and a ')' are missing.

If the table field *Severity Indicator* is defined as TEXT:

```
myIndicator = "Select * from tbl_ASPACSplitInventorySelect where ([Severity Indicator] = '" & cstr(Me.cboIndicator) & "');"
```

If the table field *Severity Indicator* is defined as NUMBER:

```
myIndicator = "Select * from tbl_ASPACSplitInventorySelect where ([Severity Indicator] = " & cstr(Me.cboIndicator) & ");"
```

Please note that before this statement it would be useful to check the value of Me.cboIndicator, with something like:

```
If not isnull(Me.cboIndicator) and not isempty(Me.cboIndicator) then ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and you indicated what I needed. @HansUp helped me through the answering of this posts. Thank you both for taking time out of your schedules to further improve the development community!!

Comment: In order to keep this site clean, please set your question as answered.